# ASP Required Field Validator shows asterisk instead of Error Message

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I've done some searching around and seem to be the only one with this sort of issue. I have a few asp:RequiredFieldValidator on my form and basically what happens is that when the validation is tripped, only a red asterisk shows up and not my error message.

Here is the validator:
`<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" CssClass="label label-danger"
ControlToValidate="email" ErrorMessage="Please provide an email address."
Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" Text="Please provide an email address." />`

And here is the control being validated:
`<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ID="email" placeholder="First.Last" ClientIDMode="Static" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox><span class="input-group-addon">@ourdomain.com</span>`

All of this is inside a master page and an update panel.

Comment: Try removing the css class `label-danger` from the validator.

Comment: Took out the CssClass property entirely and no luck.

Comment: What browser are you using maybe it's using the cache

Comment: @user3468982 Firefox and IE have the same problem

Comment: try setting a validation group on your textbox and the validator

Comment: @user3468982 gave it a shot with `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" CssClass="label label-danger" ControlToValidate="email" ErrorMessage="Please provide an email address."
Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" Text="Please provide an email address." ValidationGroup="contactInfo" />` and added the same to the text field. Same thing. The validation itself is working perfect, it is just that the message does not show up.

Comment: I copy pasted your code on my asp page and the error message is displayed.

Comment: Are you using a ValidationSummary as well?

Comment: @user3468982 In that case, I'm thinking it has to do with the master page or the update panel that it resides in.

Comment: Do you have a ValidationSummary control? If not, what happens when you add one?

Comment: @IanNewson I just added one to test, and I get no messages on it, but the asterisk still appears where the validation is

Answer (score 0):

To show only the asterisk instead of Error Message type the asterisk into the tag

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" CssClass="label label-danger"
    ControlToValidate="email" ErrorMessage="Please provide an email address."
    Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" Text="Please provide an email address.">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

The span will display * on the validator and the validator summary will show the complete message